# c++ analog of c# "is" keyword

Tags: c++

I'm rewriting this c# code to c++:

```
foreach (var index in indexes)
{
    if (index is MaWorker)
    {
        (index as MaWorker).needCalculate = true;
    }
    if (index is RocWorker)
    {
        (index as RocWorker).needCalculate = true;
    }
}
```

What is the best c++ analog? What should I use instead of C# `is` keyword?

Comment: You need to use either [dynamic_cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast) or keep needCalculate in parent class. (Parent class of ManWorker and RocWorker which is of same type as index)

Comment: cant you just put `needCalculate`  in the base class?

Comment: No I can't put to the base class and I don't want to introduce extra class just for that. In reality I have more "if is" conditions with different tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++11 has foreach too, and automatic type inference. So, assuming you have a modern compiler and C++11 enabled:

```
for (auto index : indexes)
{
    if (auto w = dynamic_cast<MaWorker*>(index))
    {
        w->needCalculate = true;
    }
    if (auto w = dynamic_cast<RocWorker*>(index))
    {
        w->needCalculate = true;
    }
}
```

Note that you are using `is` and `as` to each pointer. They both check for the dynamic type of the object, but you only need to check once. Fortunately C++ has this nice syntax of condition-with-declaration.

Comment: C# object references are not naked pointers. They perform reference counting. Use a shared_ptr or the conversion will not work.

Comment: @RichardHodges: What do you mean with _the conversion will not work_? This does not pretend to be a conversion of OP's whole program. Without any further context, it is impossible to give advice about the lifetimes of their objects. That is, other than generic advices, such as _use smart pointers whenever possible_.

Comment: I believe the op is looking for an analog. an analog of a c# object reference is a shared pointer since it does largely the same job. a pointer is not an analog since it does a different, lower level, job.

Comment: what if I have `error C2683: 'dynamic_cast' : 'MaWorker' is not a polymorphic type` error? can I just replace `dynamic_cast` to `static_cast`?

Comment: @javapowered: If the class is not polymorphic, then the compiler has no way to know if it is of the right type. You can use `static_cast<>`, but it will never return `NULL`, it will render _undefined behaviour_ instead. The safest solution is to make the root of your hierarchy polymorphic, for example by making its destructor virtual. You probably need a virtual destructor anyway, so double win.

Answer (score 1):

The best c++ analog is to use std::shared_ptr and std::dynamic_pointer_cast.
This is because in c# all objects are actually reference counted handles, and the analog for that in c++ is a shared_ptr.

so:

```
class Worker {};
class MaWorker : public Worker {};
class RocWorker : public Worker {};

std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Workers > > indexes;

for (const auto& index : indexes) {
  if (auto ma = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<MaWorker>(index)) {
    ma->needCalculate = true;
  }
  if (auto roc = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<RocWorker>(index)) {
    roc->needCalculate = true;
  }
}
```

However, this kind of switching on class type breaks OO principles. Why not just move the needCalculate member into the base class, or better have some base class method that notifies the object of whatever external event you are handling? Perhaps that's beyond the scope of the conversion.

Watch out though. A c# object reference is NOT the same as a c++ pointer.

Comment: You are conflating issues here. Who said the container being iterated over has to own the objects?

Comment: No one. The OPs question is about conversion between languages, not merely dispatching on type.